# Где ссылка на коды населенных пунктов или станций?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

> Код населенного пункта или код станции можно получить из адресной строки, пользуясь Яндекс.Расписаниями. Например, из адресной строки - [1](https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/reference/schedule-point-point-docpage/)

Где ссылка на эти коды?

Answer (score 2):

После указания пунктов отправления и прибытия на странице https://rasp.yandex.ru будет сформирована URL строка с кодами этих пунктов. Второй способ найти эти коды - выполнить запрос к API из [этого](https://tech.yandex.ru/rasp/doc/reference/stations-list-docpage/) раздела.